# elegantly return a Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala, coming over from Java, and I'm having trouble elegantly returning Map from this function.  What's an elegant way to rewrite this function so there's a single exit point?

```
foo(): Map[TypeDef, DataFrame]
if (someTest) {
    if (someTest2) {
         val a = A()
         val b = B()
         Map(a -> b)
    } else {
       Map.empty
    }
} else {
    Map.empty
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it like:

```
def foo(): Map[TypeDef, DataFrame] = 
    if (someTest && someTest2) Map(A() -> B()) else Map.empty
```